# I'm trying to find the maximum value of the "Close" from a CSV of previous years stock data but the code isn't working

Tags: python, pandas

The code is as follows. It doesn't give the output when the idxmax function is used. How am I using it wrong here?

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
def get_max_close(symbol):
    df = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/vicko/Desktop/CSV/{}.csv".format(symbol))
    return df['Close'].idxmax(axis=None, skipna=True)

def test_run():
    for symbol in ['NIFTY', 'CLZ2014']:
        print ("Max Close")
        print (symbol)
        print (get_max_close(symbol))

if __name__== "__main__":
    test_run()
```

Comment: Can you please provide the head of df['Close'] and the type of that column.

Comment: @Greg The file is corrupt. That's why the code stopped when the code ran.

Answer (score 0):

.idxmax will return the index of the max number.  Try df['Close'].max(axis=1) instead.  [Here is the link.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html)

Comment: ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Not working. And in case of idxmax, there's no return value. It shows an error there too

Comment: The output comes for the first CSV "NIFTY". Error occurs during the second file.